# Find a range address

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select some range based on cells value, as they might be each time in different column.

So my first thought was something like below, but I'm not sure if that's the right way?

```
Sub RangeBetween()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim totalRange As Range
Dim c1, c2 As Integer

c1 = 1
    Do Until Name = "A"
        Name = Cells(1, c1)
        c1 = c1 + 1
    Loop
someA= c1 - 1

c2 = 1
    Do Until Name = "B"
        Name = Cells(1, c2)
        c2 = c2 + 1
    Loop
someB= c2 - 1

Set rng1 = Range("???")
Set rng2 = Range("???")

Set totalRange = Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
    totalRange .Select
    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: c1 is declared implicitly as variant. Put Dim C1 As Long (And Dim C2 As Long; long preferred over Integer). Also, you could potentially loop all of column A etc. was this your intention?

Comment: look into Range.Rind() method.  It will return a range object.

Comment: Sorry Range.Find() method

Comment: I will look into range.find, maybe that will work in my case. @QHarr my intention is to find a range between 2 cells, Let's say i will have columns called "ID", "Name", "Surname" in my files, but they will be each time in different column. Sometimes that can be range can be in D1:G1, sometimes I1:K1, so i want my macro to find that range and copy it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use Match()

```
Sub RangeBetween()


Dim totalRange As Range
Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long


c1 = 0
c2 = 0
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        c1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("A", .Rows(1), 0)
        c2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("B", .Rows(1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If c1 > 0 And c2 > 0 Then
        Set totalRange = .Range(.Cells(1, c1), .Cells(1, c2))
        totalRange.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "One or both items not found in range"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That works just fine, but I'm not sure if It will work with what I want to do next. because I tried to use totalRange(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select - to select all data below and it is not working. Not sure  how I could do that.

Comment: New questions get new post.  This one answered the question you asked.

Comment: @YowE3K your are correct, I made the wrong assumption, it has been fixed, interestingly enough, the OP stated that it works fine.  ??????

Comment: "it works fine" often means "it doesn't crash, so it must be better than what I wrote myself" :D

Comment: As to my error, been a long day. and it is only 1pm.

Comment: I wasnt specific, here I only asked how to find a range between cells and this part of code works.